# SlickGrid- Need of insensitive case filter

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, slickgrid, case-insensitive

Is there's a way to change the filter from sensitive case to insensitive?

Thank you.

Comment: Guessing you are talking about the DataView filter, the implementation of the filter functionality is totally up to you. Note the filter function used in the SlickGrid examples - that function is set as the filter using dataView.setFilter(your_function_here).
So implement the filter function as you want and set it to the dataView.

Comment: Thank you again man! your'e the best! :) 
Hey- here's a tip from me to you - transform your comment into an answer, than you'll get points when I'll approve your answer as the correct one. Than delete this comment :)))

Comment: & regarding my question- how can I unsensitive it? I will lowercase the dataView string, and than there won't be any issue? #thinking....

Comment: Yeah - use one case (either lower or upper) of both left-hand and right-hand side of compare and that should do it. You could use Javascript prototypes to register a function/operator for this if you will use this often in your JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are talking about the DataView filter, the implementation of the filter functionality is totally up to you. Note the filter function used in the SlickGrid examples - that function is set as the filter using dataView.setFilter(your_function_here). So implement the filter function as you want and set it to the dataView

Comment: I have commited into SG repository at Git this modification.

I think it needs to be the default behaviour, Doesn't make sense that the user will want to search using a case-sensitive filter.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/362

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the relevant section of a working example using the DataView filter.  Notice the **searchString** variable is converted to lowercase when the value is first defined and then it's compared to lowercase strings within the **myFilter** function.

```
function myFilter(item, args) {
    if (args.searchString != "" && item["FirstName"].toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString) == -1 && item["LastName"].toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

....

$("#txtSearch").keyup(function (e) {
    Slick.GlobalEditorLock.cancelCurrentEdit();
    // clear on Esc
    if (e.which == 27) {
        this.value = "";
    }
    searchString = this.value.toLowerCase();
    updateFilter();
});

function updateFilter() {
    dataView.setFilterArgs({
        searchString: searchString
    });
    dataView.refresh();
}

// initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.setFilterArgs({
    searchString: searchString
});
dataView.setFilter(myFilter);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function filter(item) {
    // String Should Match Each Other
    /* for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
      if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
        var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
        if (item[c.field] != columnFilters[columnId]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    } */

    for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
        if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
            var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
// This Case Sensitive
//if (!(item[c.field] && (""+item[c.field]).indexOf(columnFilters[columnId]) !== -1)) {
            if (!(item[c.field] && (""+item[c.field].toLowerCase()).indexOf(columnFilters[columnId].toLowerCase()) !== -1)) { 
// Case in-Sensitive
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
```